# Google Cloud - nodejs deploy yarn could not be run

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

[image]

When deploying nodejs application in Google Cloud I'm getting attached image error.

I was trying sample nodejs application from below attached url.
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world

Answer (score 0):

`yarn` will not be installed with Node.js, the default package manager is `npm`, if you want to use `yarn`, you need to install it first `npm install -g yarn`.